# how to get max value and add new values

Tags: php, mysql

My table contain two column named **empid** and **empdesciption.** I want to add new values to it by getting the maximum value of **empid** also the previous **empid** values should be only be in read only format and display all the details in a php page.

Comment: So what have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Janick Bernet's comment + show an example.

Comment: how about making the *empid* column to be **autoincrement**?

Comment: I think you could frame your question in other words, not clear with the requirement.